# Generating dynamic meta tags in Angular and having it actually show up in a Twitter-style card preview?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm building a dynamic site. There's a Java app serving up a REST-ish JSON API and an Angular9 front end. I want to be able to post a link to a specific URL within the app on Twitter, Slack, or anywhere else that supports Twitter-card-style previews and have the surrounding environment unfurl a dynamic preview specific to that individual, virtual "page" in my single-page app.

I'm using Angular's `Meta` service and successfully setting the meta tags on the page, but it obviously doesn't happen until the JS runs. The only way I've found to get the meta tags loaded early enough to be available to Twitter or Slack is to hardcode them in my index.html. I've heard that Google's and Bing's crawlers will run client-side JS during indexing, but as far as I can tell, Twitter's and Slack's card preview mechanisms don't. I haven't tested Facebook or anything else, but I expect similar results. For the time being, I don't care about SEO on this app, so the Google/Bing thing doesn't help me.

Now, obviously, one option would be to reimplement a portion of my dynamic code in a server-side language, and let the server generate the index.html on the fly, but *I really don't want to do that.* I currently have a very nice separation of concerns between my UI and my API; everything is nice and clean. My backend server is nice and lightweight, free of any of the libraries I'd need to introduce.

If it matters, the front end is served by nginx. For the development phase, nginx and the Java back end are running on the same host, but as it stands there's no reason I couldn't split them up, and I don't want to change that.

The dynamically generated content is looked up from a database using a portion of the URL which is not available at build time, so re-generating the static index.html with the underlying data is not an option, and Angular's nature as a single-page app precludes having multiple static HTML source files.

Am I missing an option that would work? I'm hoping there's some additional `<meta>` tag I can add to my source that tells the surrounding environment to run the JS before reading the rest of the tags, but I've been able to find no evidence that such a thing exists.

EDIT: as I expect that the technical answer to this question is "no, you're not missing anything; you have to do it server side," I'd be interested in answers to a subquestion: how best to do that without ruining my separation of concerns?

Here's the idea I have: create an API on the back end that can generate the meta tags, or at least the summary, title, description, and image URL to be used in the meta tags. Then run something lightweight on the UI side and configure nginx to proxy requests for index.html (or its replacement) to it. Then that thing would form a request to the backend and splice the results into the page before serving it back to nginx. My only server-side dynamic experience is with Java (waaaay too heavy for this) and PHP ([ew](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)). What's out there that's performant, lightweight (in terms of RAM), capable of making calls to a REST API, and then inserting the resulting content into an HTML document without too much fuss? I assume I could accomplish all of this with Django, Rails, Node.js, Flask, and probably a hundred other things.

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/universal

You should look into Angular SSR.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that allows build-time dynamism. I need run-time dynamism. New data is getting generated into a database all the time, and the data I need to render into the meta tags comes from the database.

Comment: `SSR` is run-time. `pre-rendering` is build-time. so I think it should work. I use it with Vue and nuxt and it works perfectly. I think Angular should be able to do the same. check this https://www.toptal.com/front-end/client-side-vs-server-side-pre-rendering

Comment: From that link: "This is why this solution can be useful for small applications—you can see how painful it would be if you had a few hundred pages."

I have tens of thousands of database-driven URLS (and growing) that would all need unique content in their `meta` tags. I'm not saying you're wrong, but I don't see how to apply that to my situation.

Comment: Also, my server is a cheap VPS with 1GB of RAM to keep costs low. I don't have good feelings about running a medium-large Javascript app in Node alongside my Java-based back end and staying within that memory footprint. I'd strongly prefer to keep the Angular app on the client side and just use something small to serve a dynamic index.html.

Comment: it's painful for pre rendering correct, SSR is different. basically when google crawls to your webpage, it renders on the server side and returns the meta tags. client side renders an empty page first, and after 1-2 seconds, it modifies the HTML and meta tags. Pre rending is different as the page is already rendered when google crawls into your page, that means it's not dynamic. anyways I guess if you have a large app, you gotta pay more for SEO.

Comment: This isn't about SEO. It's about Twitter-style previews. :)

Regardless, I'm not finding any docs that tell me _how_ to switch my existing client-side Angular app to use SSR, nor that explain how it works in sufficient detail that I could figure it out myself. The links you provided explain what it is and seem designed to deter users like me from choosing it, but nothing about how.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the server to use Angular Universal, you can rename your index.html into index.php and then, for every page request, you can generate the meta tags and the title tag on the server but be sure that it is the same metadata that the Angular app would set. This way you don't have to render the whole page on the server, only the parts that are important for social media crawlers.

Comment: Somehow I missed this answer when you posted it. This is along the lines of what I want (some kind of server-side processor), but frankly, I despise PHP for reasons not relevant here, and I'm seeking something else. It is not and will never be installed on my server. In the intervening time since I first asked this question, I've learned Go, and if I get time to revisit this thing, I'm going to try to build the thing I want using Go templates. Should be fast and efficient!

Comment: Yeah, any other language should do the job as well. Btw. people should stop blaming php, it improved quite a lot over time, and now it's more powerful than ever

Comment: It has certainly improved a lot, this is true. But not enough to make me like it, or to give me good feelings about running it on my own server. 

Thanks to Wordpress’s popularity, it’s also one of the most popular attack vectors. Since I can't hope to become an expert on writing safe, defensive PHP (without embedding myself in a language I don’t enjoy), I’d rather run something else.